# Terminology for an API where users implement methods

Tags: terminology, api-design

There is an approach in library API design where the user must implement a subclass (or, sometimes, a set of functions) in order to use the API.  For example, libraries may provide an (abstract) base class which the user must extend, instantiate, and then pass back to the library.

Is there a specific name for this kind of approach?

(The phrase "Service Provider Interface" seems to appear in Java but not elsewhere.  It is also widely used in "Plug-in" architectures but does not seem to be the same thing.)

Comment: I suppose you would use this term, for example, in documentation or marketing material:  "We provide a [term] API for you..."?

Comment: Exactly, that's the kind of situation one might use this term in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term **abstract** has a precise well known definition within the programming community, so I think we could say

> We provide an **abstract API** consisting of a set of abstract classes
>   and interfaces designed for you to extend and customise with concrete
>   implementations.

and most developers would be familiar with the intended meaning.